# Pythonanywhere 'staticfiles' is not a valid tag library: Template library staticfiles not found

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, pythonanywhere

In pythonanywhere, I'm using virtualenv with Django 1.7 and Python 2.7

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/movies/pantherlist/movies/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pantherlist.movies',
)
```

**wsgi.py**

```
activate_this = '/home/movies/.virtualenvs/django17/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
.
.#path setup already done here
.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am getting error

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
'staticfiles' is not a valid tag library: Template library staticfiles not found, tried django.templatetags.staticfiles,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.staticfiles

**Exception Location:   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in load, line 1054**

Error at
**index.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you haven't reloaded your web app since adding the virtualenv activation to your wsgi file, or you're not using the wsgi file that you think you're using. The error location that Django is reporting (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py) is in the default system Django on PythonAnywhere , not the Django in your virtualenv.

Comment: You are right. I already fixed that. I created a wsgi file in my project folder and was changing that. Thats a mistake. I should have directly changed the pythonanywhere wsgi file in the 'web' tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

And now you can use it in this way:

```
{% static "images/hi.jpg" as myphoto %}
<img src="{{ myphoto }}" alt="Hi!" />
```

This example is from django doc for 1.7 version/